# How does capital gains tax work when buying the same stock at different times?

Tags: united-states, taxes, stocks, capital-gains-tax

Say, for example, I bought 10 shares of stock XYZ on January 1, 2018 and I buy another 10 shares of the same stock on April 1, 2018. Then I wait until January 1, 2019 to sell all the shares of my XYZ stock. Would the long term capital gain tax affect only the first 10 shares I bought since I've only held those shares for 1 year? Or would it affect all 20 shares that I sold?

Comment: The proceeds on *all* the shares would be subject to capital gains tax; the difference is whether they would be taxed as *short*-term (at this time, at the same rate as personal income) or as *long*-term (at a lower tax rate) gains.

Comment: Related: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/87042/how-much-can-i-withdraw-from-betterment-and-be-considered-long-term-investment/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The long/short term distinction is made per *lot*.  So you would pay long-term gains tax on the profit made from the first lot of 10 shares, and short-term capital gains tax on profit made from the second lot of 10 shares.

Comment: And to be clear, the option for one to choose which lots to sell, for partial sales, is gone. It's first in first out, from here on in.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer Interesting. I wasn't aware of that change.

Comment: The new code has a good number of delightful changes that will catch many by surprise. No more "roth recharacterization" is my favorite...

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer Thought the FIFO rule was later removed? Did it come back in the final bill? Do you have a source?

Comment: I will double check. And advise.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer See [this article](https://www.thecapitalideas.com/articles/2018-tax-reforms-mean-for-investors) for example.  FIFO was removed.

Comment: I'm apologize in advance if this is a stupid question, but is the FIFO rule considered bad or good? Wouldn't FIFO be good since you're automatically selling the oldest shares you have thus allowing you to have the highest chance at long term capital gains?

Comment: @Joe - I stand corrected. It was removed from the final bill. (A lot of other bad things remained, but forced FIFO was pulled out)

Comment: @AJGoudel It's "bad" from an investor's point of view, as the current law allows you to pick and choose which shares to consider to have sold - meaning you can choose the most advantageous, not so much from an age point of view as from a cost basis point of view.  Imagine you have 200 shares of AAPL: 100 that you bought as a child in 1980 at their IPO, and 100 that you bought on Dec 18, 2017 ($2/share higher than today).  You might want to sell 100 shares and re-buy them immediately, in order to take a $200 tax loss to offset some taxes, but definitely not prefer to sell the IPO shares!

Comment: Well, not immediately. That would be a wash sale, need to replace the shares 30+ days before or after the sale.